# Prestashop Smarty language string inside a js file

Tags: javascript, php, smarty, prestashop

I am making some changes to the module "Blockcart" and I need to insert inside the ajax-cart.js file a language string, for example "{l s='text'}"

in this place:

```
content += '<span class="pname">' + {l s='text'} + '</span>';
```

How can I make it work?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18422642/prestashop-how-to-add-static-contents-in-different-language-in-tpl-file

Answer (score 1):

There are several options to achieve the desired effect.

**One option** is to define the variable as a global one in the layout, eg. header HTML part of the page with

```
<script>
var pName = "{l s='text'}";
</script>
```

and then use it in the `ajax-cart.js` with

```
content += '<span class="pname">' + pName + '</span>';
```

---

**Another option** is to use a data attribute:

Find a HTML wrapper element of the cart DOM and insert the following data attribute, or you can use any other accessible HTML element.

```
<div id="shopping-cart-wrapper" data-label-pname="{l text='text'}"></div>
```

Then in the `ajax-cart.js` use:

```
content += '<span class="pname">' + $('#shopping-cart-wrapper').data('label-pname') + '</span>';
```